# If $A=(0,1)$ in a topological space, how would you find its boundary?

Tags: general-topology

Let $\partial A=\overline{A}\cap\overline{X\setminus A}$ be the boundary of $A$ in $X$.

Given $A=(0,1)$, $\overline{A}=[0,1]$ and $\overline{X\setminus A}=(-\infty,0]\cap[0,+\infty)$, then
$$\partial A=[0,1] \cap \big((-\infty, 0] \cap [0,+\infty)\big)=\{0,1\}\text.$$
So, $\partial A=\{0,1\}$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the procedure is right (you just apply the topological definition of boundary, actually). Assuming that $X=\mathbb R$ with the usual (Euclidean) topology, of course.

Only one note: the closure of the complementary set $\overline{X\smallsetminus A}$ is $(-\infty,0]\cup[1,+\infty)$, not $(-\infty,0]\cap[0,+\infty)$.
But I assumed it was just a typo, since you got the correct final result.

Comment: Yes that I meant to take the union and I considered X=R with the standard topology. Thank you